# How to display unlimited rows in Content Query Web Part?

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

I want to display unlimited number of rows using Content Query Web Part.

Is it possible? if yes then how and if no then what is maximum row limit supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the below option in CQWP you can control the item limit to display:

[image]